# How to make category RSS feeds show full content

Tags: categories, feed, multisite

I'm trying to fix a friend's feed to show full content in the category feed instead of only a summary.  He's already done the setting bit, but it still doesn't seem to work.  Thoughts?

EDIT: The feed in question is http://blogs.gnome.org/happyaron/category/debian/feed/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Full Text Feed](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/full-text-feed/) plugin shows full content....follow the installation steps there,and then goto settings->Reading->For each article in a feed, show=>select Full text and save.it'll work.if you want to implement via the code means,

```
<?php if (get_option('rss_use_excerpt')) : ?>
        <description><![CDATA[<?php the_excerpt_rss() ?>]]></description>
<?php else : ?>
        <description><![CDATA[<?php the_excerpt_rss() ?>]]></description>
    <?php if ( strlen( $post->post_content ) > 0 ) : ?>
        <content:encoded><![CDATA[<?php the_content() ?>]]></content:encoded>
    <?php else : ?>
        <content:encoded><![CDATA[<?php the_excerpt_rss() ?>]]></content:encoded>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```